# how to write a program that gets gateway info in fiddler

Tags: configuration, fiddler

In Fiddler when I look at Tools > Fiddler Options > Connections > Show Gate Info,
I see the upstream gateway, which is calculated from the IE settings it adopts on startup.

Is there a method to get the gateway info.
Or is there a way fiddler saves the gateway info, which I can program to read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gateway info in Fiddler's About dialog shows the upstream gateway, which is calculated from the IE settings it adopts on startup.

Fiddler registry settings are subject to change at any time, and should generally be set using only the Fiddler user-interface. In particular, the settings should not be set, or directly replied upon, by Fiddler Extensions.

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Fiddler2

for more update check http://fiddler.wikidot.com/registrysettings